# Convert an array of string into JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an array of string

```
var ids = new string[]
{
    "1408576188",
    "1750854738",
    "100001058197465"
};
```

I want to pass this array of string as a json array into an API. For now, the API **cannot** accept the string returned from :

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ids);
```

So I am figuring out that I am able to use the API by turning my `ids` array into a `JArray` object.

```
JArray.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ids));
```

As you can see, I am doing a two operation in here, first I serialize the `ids` array, then I parse the result into `JArray`. Is there any way to convert my `ids` array directly into `JArray` object?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Did you try the `FromObject` method:

```
var array = JArray.FromObject(ids);
```

Comment: Just tried this and it works great. Thanks! I've looked in JArray members for this but I think my eyes fails me :(